# What does the term "hearing Mass" mean?

Tags: catholicism, terminology, mass

Sometimes people use the term "hearing Mass".  For example, it is used in the [Six Precepts of the Church](https://www.preces-latinae.org/thesaurus/Numeri/SexPrae.html) where it is a translation of the Latin "*Missam audire*":

> 1. To hear Mass on Sundays and Holy Days of Obligation and to refrain from servile work.
> 2. Diebus Dominicis ceterisque festis de praecepto Missam audire et ab operibus servilibus vacare.

What does the term "hearing Mass" mean?

What about deaf people who cannot hear?

Perhaps "hearing" could be a problematic translation?

Answer (score 3):

**What does the term hearing Mass mean?**

Although the Latin text does employ the word to ***hear*** (***audire***) in this passage, the term or expression would be better translated as to mean *attend* or *participate* in the mass in this circumstance.

> [Praecepta Ecclesiae](https://www.vatican.va/archive/catechism_lt/p3s1c3a3_lt.htm#II.%20Praecepta%20Ecclesiae)
>
> 2042 Primum praeceptum («Diebus Dominicis ceterisque festis de praecepto Missam **audire** et ab operibus servilibus vacare») a fidelibus exigit diem in quo resurrectio Domini commemoratur, necnon praecipuas liturgicas festivitates quae Domini, beatae Virginis Mariae et sanctorum honorant mysteria, sanctificare, imprimis eucharisticam **participando** celebrationem, in qua communitas congregatur christiana, atque ab illis requiescere laboribus et negotiis quae talem horum dierum sanctificationem possint impedire.

> [The Precepts of the Church](https://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG0015/__P75.HTM)
>
> 2042 The first precept (“You shall **attend** Mass on Sundays and holy days of obligation.") requires the faithful to **participate** in the Eucharistic celebration when the Christian community gathers together on the day commemorating the Resurrection of the Lord.

In the Extraordinary Rite of the Mass, the Canon of the Mass is said in a low voice and is inaudible to most except the ministers who are onear the altar. So to think ***audire*** is to be literally translated as to means ***hear*** the mass is a misconception.

Comment: So "audio" has a broader meaning than just "I hear"? Or did the "I hear" have another meaning in the old days?

Comment: @harryjansson At least in this circumstance.